# Starting another app's activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

If I start another app's activity with an implicit intent, what does the activity back stack look like and why? I found in the docs that 'the activity runs in a separate process' - does this mean the activity is in its own backstack?

Answer (score 2):

The backstack would still be your activity.  Running in a separate process means that they run in separate Linux processes-  that they have memory protection and cannot access each other's variables (they communicate by Bundle, which is passed from one to the other via IPC).

Comment: Yes.  and the full backstack still exists-  if you have activity A start Activity B start ActivityInOtherApk then the backstack would be A->B->ActivityInOtherApk

Comment: Okay that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I guess it really depends on the flags that you pass in. Try going through 
[the developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for more info.